# Compact subset implies compact subset for each connected component.

Tags: general-topology

Let $U\subset \mathbb R^N$ such that $U=\bigcup_{i=1}^N U_i$ where $U_i\cap U_j=\varnothing$ for $i\neq j$ and $N$ is finite. Let $V\subset\subset U$, i.e., $\bar V\subset U$. Define $V_i:=V\cap U_i$. Do we have $V_i\subset\subset U_i$ as well? (We use standard topology in $\mathbb R^N$.)

I think the answer is yes, and I think I saw a lemma which states a similar result in some textbook but I can't find it now... If you know a reference, please direct me there. Thank you!

Comment: Are there any restrictions on what the sets $U_i$ are?

Comment: @EricWofsey Yes, they are disjoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without assuming disjointness, it is *false*: Choose $U_1 = (0, 2)$, $U_2 = (1, 3)$ and $V = [1, 2]$.

---

If you assume that the sets $U_i$ are disjoint open sets (I guess you are assuming this, because you use the word "component"), then the answer is *true*. It follows from considering

$$V \cap U_1 = V \cap \left(\bigcap_{i \ne 1} U_i^c\right)$$

and recalling that the intersection of a compact set with a closed set is compact.

Comment: Yes, they are disjoint. Please give me a sec let me read your answer. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

Let $i$ be given.

(i) If $j\neq i$ then $\overline {V_i}\subseteq U_j ^C$, as $U_j ^C$ is closed and contains $U_i$ (here we use the fact that the $U$'s are pairwise disjoint) and thus contains $V_i$.

(ii) As $\overline V\subseteq U$, clearly $\overline {V_i}\subseteq U$.

Combining (i) and (ii), we find that $\overline {V_i}\subseteq U_i$.

---

By the way, you may want to choose a different title because this has nothing to do with compactness or connected components